# Showing the chosen SKU of a Configurable Product in the cart

Tags: php, magento

Following problem: You've got a Configurable product with one random attribute. The customer chooses, for example, a size "XXL", and puts this into the cart. In the cart, I am showing the SKU with:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$item_ID = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item_ID);

echo $_product->getSku();
```

Now it shows the SKU of the Configurable Product. But I want to show the SKU of the chosen product (Simple Prodcut with the size XXL e.x.). How is that possible? I `print_r`'ed all those item-data, product-data and so on, but the only thing, which is getable is a Collection of associated Products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
    // check whether there are childrens for this product
    $_product->getHasChildren(); 
    // get the simple products behind the configurable product
    $_product->getChildren();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: But like this I will get all Children of that CProduct, not the specific one, I configured before

Comment: have you tried to use `$this->getUsedProductAttributes()` to compare the product in cart and the simple product? There's also `$this->getUsedProducts();` in the class, but i don't know if that is spitting out some useful informations for the simple or for the configurable product, try it by yourself. Good Luck!

Comment: I will try it with the getUsedProductAttributes() method. But due the fact, that I havn't found this method yet, I think its possible to solve the problem with that one. Thanks!